# If $\gamma (t)$ satisfies $\gamma (t) \cdot \gamma '(t) \times \gamma '' (t)=1$, then $\gamma '''=p_{0} \gamma +p_{1} \gamma '$

Tags: differential-geometry, solution-verification

I need help with the following:

> Prove that if $\gamma (t)$ satisfies $\gamma (t) \cdot \gamma '(t) \times \gamma '' (t)=1$ for all t, then $\gamma '''=p_{0} \gamma +p_{1} \gamma '$ for certain scalar functions $p_{0} (t), p_{1} (t)$

What I tried was to derive the triple scalar product in a similar way to what is done with the dot product and then I got the following expression:

$ \gamma' \cdot \gamma' \times \gamma''+\gamma \cdot (\gamma'' \times \gamma''+\gamma' \times \gamma''')=0 $

Now, we know that the cross product of a vector with itself is 0, so our expression reduces to the following:

$\gamma \cdot \gamma' \times \gamma '''=0$

And now applying the dot product by $\gamma ''$

$\gamma''' \cdot \gamma'' \cdot (\gamma \times \gamma')=0$

Now taking our hypothesis we have:

$\gamma'''=0$

Could you please tell me if I have an error, if my proof is correct or if this is not the way to solve this problem please, thank you very much.

Comment: Can you explain in index notation what you mean by $a\cdot b\cdot(c\times d)$ for vectors $a,\,b,\,c,\,d$?

Comment: True, as @J.G. mentions in his answer, that expression doesn't even make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that $\gamma\cdot\gamma^\prime\times\gamma^{(3)}=0$, but your next step is invalid because you're dotting a vector with a scalar and the resulting expression doesn't even make sense. What you should argue is $\gamma\times\gamma^\prime\cdot\gamma^{(3)}=0$ implies $\gamma^{(3)}$ is orthogonal to $\gamma\times\gamma^\prime$ and hence in the plane $\gamma,\,\gamma^\prime$ span.

Comment: Thanks, perfectly understood.

Answer (score 1):

Differentiating we get
$$\langle\gamma,\gamma'\times\gamma''\rangle=1\Longrightarrow\langle\gamma',\gamma'\times\gamma''\rangle+\langle\gamma,\gamma''\times\gamma''+\gamma'\times\gamma'''\rangle=0\Longrightarrow\langle\gamma,\gamma'\times\gamma'''\rangle=0$$
By the circular shift property of the Triple Product we know $0=\langle\gamma,\gamma'\times\gamma'''\rangle=\langle\gamma''',\gamma\times\gamma'\rangle$, then $\gamma'''\in\text{span}\{\gamma,\gamma'\}$.

Answer (score 1):

From $0=\gamma \cdot \gamma' \times \gamma '''=\det(
\gamma,\gamma',\gamma''')$ you know that $\gamma,\gamma',\gamma'''$ are linearly dependent.